# Moving children and descendants on level of 1st parent/ancestor with XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Having a problem coming up with a solution for this XSLT transform.

Source input:

```
<root>
    <title>Title here.</title>
    <div>
        <p>Text here.</p>
        <div>
            <p>Text here.</p>
            <div>
                <p>Text here.</p>
                <div>
                    <p>Text here.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</root>
```

Desired output:

```
<root>
    <title>Title here.</title>
    <div>
        <p>Text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Text here.</p>
    </div>
</root>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks pretty simple. What's the problem?

Comment: Is it just Div tags that need to be moved up, or can there be other tags? What are the exact rules for the transformation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the question Tim C asked (other named tags?), you may simply use:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <root>
    <xsl:for-each select="//div/p">
      <div><xsl:copy-of select="." /></div>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to start off with is the identity template

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This will copy elements as-is, so you only need to write templates for elements you wish to transform. In this case, it looks like you want to transform elements with have at least one element as a child (apart from the root element), so the template match will look like this

```
<xsl:template match="*/*[*]">
```

Within this, you need to copy the element, but then process only child nodes that don't have other elements as children

```
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::*[*])]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
```

Finally, after this copy, you can select the child elements with children, so they are copied after the current element

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[*]"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="*/*[*]">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::*[*])]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[*]"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML sample, the following is output

```
<root>
    <title>Title here.</title>
    <div>
        <p>Text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Text here.</p>
    </div>
</root>
```

This is quite a generic solution, and will work with all tag names, not just DIV tags.